# Using for each loop to get value from XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm trying to get values from XML file, the problem is that I had to loop in  "orderLineItem" to get its sub value. How can I improve my nested loop? Or is there any way to use only one loop to get each item?

XML

```
<orders>
  <orderLineItem>
    <tradeItemId>
      <additionalTradeItemId>
        <type>BUYER_ASSIGNED</type>
        <value>12378</value>
      </additionalTradeItemId>
    </tradeItemId>
    <description>ITEM DESC</description>
    <requestedQuantity>
      <unitOfMeasure>CASE</unitOfMeasure>
      <value>71.00</value>
    </requestedQuantity>
    <amountPerUnit>
      <monetaryAmount>1000</monetaryAmount>
    </amountPerUnit>
    <netPrice>
      <monetaryAmount>900</monetaryAmount>
    </netPrice>
  </orderLineItem>
  <orderLineItem>
    <tradeItemId>
      <additionalTradeItemId>
        <type>BUYER_ASSIGNED</type>
        <value>12379</value>
      </additionalTradeItemId>
    </tradeItemId>
    <description>ITEM DESC1</description>
    <requestedQuantity>
      <unitOfMeasure>CASE</unitOfMeasure>
      <value>50.00</value>
    </requestedQuantity>
    <amountPerUnit>
      <monetaryAmount>1200</monetaryAmount>
    </amountPerUnit>
    <netPrice>
      <monetaryAmount>1150</monetaryAmount>
    </netPrice>
  </orderLineItem>
</orders>
```

My Code

```
nodesList = root.SelectNodes("//orders/orderLineItem/tradeItemId/additionalTradeItemId")
nodesListDesc = root.SelectNodes("//orders/orderLineItem")
nodesListQty = root.SelectNodes("//orders/orderLineItem/requestedQuantity")


For Each node In nodesList
   xmlInvtID = EmptyStringToNull(node("value").InnerText)

   For Each nodeDesc In nodesListDesc
       xmlItemDesc = EmptyStringToNull(nodeDesc("description").InnerText)
   Next

   For Each nodeQty In nodesListQty
       qty = EmptyStringToNull(nodeQty("value").InnerText)
   Next
Next
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to add the required result for the example data, please?

Answer (score 0):

I found using [XElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement) and LINQ to be the cleanest.

First, some test data (please see [XML Literals Overview (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/xml/xml-literals-overview) for how `test = <orders> etc,.` works):

```
Dim test As XElement
' The XElement could be loaded from a file or from a literal...
'to load from file:
' test = XElement.Load("path here")

'for testing, use an XML literal:
test = <orders>
           <orderLineItem>
               <tradeItemId>
                   <additionalTradeItemId>
                       <type>BUYER_ASSIGNED</type>
                       <value>12378</value>
                   </additionalTradeItemId>
               </tradeItemId>
               <description>ITEM DESC</description>
               <requestedQuantity>
                   <unitOfMeasure>CASE</unitOfMeasure>
                   <value>71.00</value>
               </requestedQuantity>
               <amountPerUnit>
                   <monetaryAmount>1000</monetaryAmount>
               </amountPerUnit>
               <netPrice>
                   <monetaryAmount>900</monetaryAmount>
               </netPrice>
           </orderLineItem>
           <orderLineItem>
               <tradeItemId>
                   <additionalTradeItemId>
                       <type>BUYER_ASSIGNED</type>
                       <value>12379</value>
                   </additionalTradeItemId>
               </tradeItemId>
               <description>ITEM DESC1</description>
               <requestedQuantity>
                   <unitOfMeasure>CASE</unitOfMeasure>
                   <value>50.00</value>
               </requestedQuantity>
               <amountPerUnit>
                   <monetaryAmount>1200</monetaryAmount>
               </amountPerUnit>
               <netPrice>
                   <monetaryAmount>1150</monetaryAmount>
               </netPrice>
           </orderLineItem>
       </orders>
```

And then the code:

```
Dim desc As String
Dim tival As String
Dim rqval As String

For Each oli As XElement In test.<orderLineItem>
    desc = oli.<description>.Value
    tival = oli.<tradeItemId>.<additionalTradeItemId>.<value>.Value
    rqval = oli.<requestedQuantity>.<value>.Value
    Stop
Next
```